# Record Type description not shown when creating a record in Lightning Community

Tags: lightning-experience, record-type, lightning-community

I created an object with record types and put a description on the record types. This works as expected when I am creating the record as an Internal User and the description is displayed appropriately.

[image]

---

However the behavior seems to be different when I am using this object on a Community. It does not show the description at all.

[image]

---

> Is this a known limitation for Community (*not related to this but I discovered only yesterday that overridden New buttons don't work on Community either*)? Is there any configuration required to have the record type description reflected on Community?

I am in Lightning Experience for Internal Users and in a Lightning Community utilizing out of the box details record view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reached out to Salesforce Support on this and they confirmed:

> After checking our resources, Customer Community Plus and Customer Community users, cannot access the record type description

They also provided the **[link to this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LoJpQAK)** which refers to the exact issue I was facing.

It does seem weird as why would record type description not be available to Community Users when they can actually create records of different types.